# Interface: An Edge over Abstract Class with Defualt Method (Just A Discussion)

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, java-8, default-method

With the official release of Java 8, every developers specially the java geek were very much interested for Lambda Expression. And they have the reasons to excited since scala and clojure had already made a drastic impact over the development on JVM. Now for the support to Lambda Expression, Java has launched another supporting feature called Default Methods for Interface. Bare me for the technical mistakes, since I'm not an expert in Java. 
AFAIK Abstract Class provides the similar features. **SO Do we start to accept the fact that we have taken away the major advantage of Abstract Classes.**

Expecting comments which will make me clear about the aspect that still Abstract has its own Advantage over Interface with Default Methods.

p.S I know that Abstract class can hold state of object. It can have constructors and member variables.